# Bindind Repeater to Stack List

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is code. Its not showing any compile or run time error. I debugged also then till data binding works fine. But then also controls not shown in web page!

Sample.aspx:

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="_placeHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Sample.aspx.cs:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      _placeHolder1.Controls.Add(CreateReapeater());
     }

     private Control CreateReapeater()
     {
        Repeater _repeater1 = new Repeater();
        Stack _stack1 = new Stack();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            _stack1.Push(i);
        }
        _repeater1.DataSource = _stack1;
        _repeater1.DataBind();
        return _repeater1;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for why you need to add the Repeater dynamically and not at design time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually repeater have no inbuild column structure as like gridview. so when we bind repeater dynamically we need to also create the item template for that.

You need to modify the createrepeater function as below.

```
private Control CreateReapeater()
{
    Repeater _repeater1 = new Repeater();
    Stack _stack1 = new Stack();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        _stack1.Push(i);
    }

    _repeater1.DataSource = _stack1;          
    _repeater1.DataBind();

    foreach (RepeaterItem repeatItem in _repeater1.Items)
    {
        int index = repeatItem.ItemIndex;

        RepeaterItem repeaterItem = new RepeaterItem(repeatItem.ItemIndex, ListItemType.Item);
        Label lbl = new Label();

        lbl.Text = "Item No :" + index.ToString() + "<br/>";
        repeatItem.Controls.Add(lbl);

    }



    return _repeater1;
}
```

This will resolve your issue.

Happy Coding.....

Comment: Yup! Thanks Prakash. Got it. :)